# label inside bar and on top

Tags: google-visualization, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a column chart with google charts. I could put values on top of the bar using the following:

```
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Estacionamento');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Valor');
        data.addColumn({type: 'number', role:'annotation'});
```

and creating a view:

```
chart.draw(view, {
                                height: 600,
                                width: 600,
                                series: {
                                    0: {
                                        type: 'bars'
                                    },
                                    1: {
                                        type: 'line',
                                        color: 'grey',
                                        lineWidth: 0,
                                        pointSize: 0,
                                        visibleInLegend: false
                                    }
                                },
});
```

I would like to know if it's possible to also display a value inside the bar. Right now, it's working  as a tooltip, but I want to display values without a tooltip like this image:

[image]

Comment: didn´t find a way to do it, but you could put 72.000 (30 %) as annotation and so on

Comment: with annotation it will be inside the bar?

Comment: You can set that in options with: `annotations: { alwaysOutside : true}` or false if you want it inside

Comment: Well I could find the annotation option, but didn't work on my sample =(

Comment: Can try to check if if you make a jsfiddle or something with your sample

Comment: @juvian here is: http://jsfiddle.net/wnv9ju8f/  in this sample I would like to keep the value inside the bar, but also show what's inside tooltip, above the bar.

Comment: There is no way to have 1 outside and one inside, the option is only for all anotations. Still, you could do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/wnv9ju8f/1/

Comment: No problem, good luck with your proyect

Answer (score 3):

I have a solution for you problem.... [check this example](https://jsfiddle.net/hddcv497/4/)

My solution: simple, add a column with size 0 and after that add an annotation...

select color transparent for the last column...

**Javascript Code:**

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStacked);

function drawStacked() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('timeofday', 'Time of Day');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Motivation Level');
      data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'});      
      data.addColumn('number', 'Energy Level');
      data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'});
      data.addColumn('number', 'test Level');
      data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'});
      data.addColumn('number', 'Motivation Level');
      data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'});

      data.addRows([
        [{v: [9, 0, 0], f: '8 am'},{v:40,f:"asd"},"q",{v:40,f:"asd"},"q",{v:40,f:"asd"},"q",{v:0},"q"],
        [{v: [10, 0, 0], f: '8 am'},{v:40,f:"asd"},"q",{v:40,f:"asd"},"q",{v:40,f:"asd"},"q",{v:0},"q"],
        [{v: [11, 0, 0], f: '8 am'},{v:100,f:"asd"},"q",{v:40,f:"asd"},"q",{v:40,f:"asd"},"q",{v:0},"q"],
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Motivation and Energy Level Throughout the Day',
        isStacked: true,
        annotations: {
        alwaysOutside : false,
          textStyle: {
            fontSize: 14,
            color: '#000',
            auraColor: 'none'
          }
        },
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Time of Day',
          format: 'h:mm a',
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Rating (scale of 1-10)',
          viewWindow:{
                max:200,
                min:0
              }
        },
        colors: ["blue","red","green","transparent"],
        bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

**HTML code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
```

[image]